# How to get distances from gps points from Core Location?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I'm developing an iPhone iOS4 application and one of the things that it have to do is to calculate the distance from 2 gps coordinate points.

I already know that Core Location Framework can return points from iPhones gps.

Ok, but I was wondering if there already is a method or a function to calculate the distance between these points obtained from Core Location.

So the question is:
Is there a function/method in any of IO4 SDK framework (Core Location?) that would do the job (compute the distance between 2 gps coordinate points)? Or should I actually implement it by myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [CLLocation documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) and in particular;

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```